# How to Restore Windows after Ubuntu Installation

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8, wubi

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS on my Desktop PC , which had Windows 8 installed before that.

Windows 8 now shows in the boot menu but when I click on it, it goes to blank screen with a command prompt like cursor blinking. Doesn't start.

Here's my Boot Repair paste bin :

```
 Boot Info Script e7fc706 + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info 9Feb2015]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos6)/boot/grub.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sda1 and looks at sector 298008624 of the same hard 
                       drive for core.img, but core.img can not be found at 
                       this location. No errors found in the Boot Parameter 
                       Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 8
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS 
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048       718,847       716,800   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda2             718,848   235,522,047   234,803,200   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3         235,522,048   276,482,047    40,960,000   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda4         276,484,094   312,580,095    36,096,002   5 Extended
/dev/sda5         276,484,096   280,481,791     3,997,696  82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6         280,483,840   312,580,095    32,096,256  83 Linux


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/sda1        52BA189CBA187EA3                       ntfs       System Reserved
/dev/sda2        6C46240A4623D41C                       ntfs       
/dev/sda3        D2220018220003E7                       ntfs       
/dev/sda5        f906300b-43ae-416b-90cc-2f0d2d592f2d   swap       
/dev/sda6        64120f6b-4e16-458a-bdef-61bf3d83337f   ext4       

========================= "ls -l /dev/disk/by-id" output: ======================

total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec 29 22:55 ata-TSSTcorp_CDDVDW_SH-S223C_R6356GFZ806307 -> ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 May  2 11:19 ata-WDC_WD1600AAJS-22PSA0_WD-WCAP91138408 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May  2 11:19 ata-WDC_WD1600AAJS-22PSA0_WD-WCAP91138408-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May  2 11:19 ata-WDC_WD1600AAJS-22PSA0_WD-WCAP91138408-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May  2 11:15 ata-WDC_WD1600AAJS-22PSA0_WD-WCAP91138408-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 29 22:55 ata-WDC_WD1600AAJS-22PSA0_WD-WCAP91138408-part4 -> ../../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 29 22:55 ata-WDC_WD1600AAJS-22PSA0_WD-WCAP91138408-part5 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 29 22:55 ata-WDC_WD1600AAJS-22PSA0_WD-WCAP91138408-part6 -> ../../sda6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 May  2 11:19 wwn-0x50014ee1aae85624 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May  2 11:19 wwn-0x50014ee1aae85624-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May  2 11:19 wwn-0x50014ee1aae85624-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May  2 11:15 wwn-0x50014ee1aae85624-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 29 22:55 wwn-0x50014ee1aae85624-part4 -> ../../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 29 22:55 wwn-0x50014ee1aae85624-part5 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 29 22:55 wwn-0x50014ee1aae85624-part6 -> ../../sda6

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sda6        /                        ext4       (rw,errors=remount-ro)


=========================== sda6/boot/grub/grub.cfg: 

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION :
=================== log of boot-repair 2015-05-02__11h15 ===================
boot-repair version : 4ppa33
boot-sav version : 4ppa33
glade2script version : 3.2.2~ppa47~saucy
boot-sav-extra version : 4ppa33
boot-repair is executed in installed-session (Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, trusty, Ubuntu, x86_64)
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-30-generic root=UUID=64120f6b-4e16-458a-bdef-61bf3d83337f ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
mount /dev/sda1 : Error code 14
mount -r /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
mount /dev/sda2 : Error code 14
mount -r /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda3 /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
mount /dev/sda3 : Error code 14
mount -r /dev/sda3 /mnt/boot-sav/sda3

=================== os-prober:
/dev/sda6:The OS now in use - Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS CurrentSession:linux
/dev/sda1:Windows 8 (loader):Windows:chain

=================== blkid:
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="52BA189CBA187EA3" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda2: UUID="6C46240A4623D41C" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda3: UUID="D2220018220003E7" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda5: UUID="f906300b-43ae-416b-90cc-2f0d2d592f2d" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sda6: UUID="64120f6b-4e16-458a-bdef-61bf3d83337f" TYPE="ext4"


1 disks with OS, 2 OS : 1 Linux, 0 MacOS, 1 Windows, 0 unknown type OS.

Windows not detected by os-prober on sda2.
Warning: extended partition does not start at a cylinder boundary.
DOS and Linux will interpret the contents differently.

=================== /etc/grub.d/ :
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Feb 19 01:08 grub.d
total 76
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  9424 May 16  2014 00_header
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  6058 May  8  2014 05_debian_theme
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11608 May 16  2014 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10412 May 16  2014 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1992 Mar 12  2014 20_memtest86+
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11692 May 16  2014 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1416 May 16  2014 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 May 16  2014 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 May 16  2014 41_custom
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   483 May 16  2014 README




=================== /etc/default/grub :

# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"




=================== UEFI/Legacy mode:
This installed-session is not in EFI-mode.
SecureBoot disabled.


=================== PARTITIONS & DISKS:
sda6    : sda,  not-sepboot,    grubenv-ok  grub2,  grub-pc ,   update-grub,    64, with-boot,  is-os,  not--efi--part, fstab-without-boot, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, apt-get,    grub-install,   with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   farbios,    .
sda1    : sda,  not-sepboot,    no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    is-os,  not--efi--part, part-has-no-fstab,  part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    is-winboot, nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   not-far,    /mnt/boot-sav/sda1.
sda2    : sda,  not-sepboot,    no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    is-os,  not--efi--part, part-has-no-fstab,  part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    notwinboot, nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   farbios,    /mnt/boot-sav/sda2.
sda3    : sda,  not-sepboot,    no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    no-os,  not--efi--part, part-has-no-fstab,  part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   farbios,    /mnt/boot-sav/sda3.

sda : not-GPT,  BIOSboot-not-needed,    has-no-EFIpart,     not-usb,    has-os, 2048 sectors * 512 bytes


=================== parted -l:

Model: ATA WDC WD1600AAJS-2 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 160GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
1      1049kB  368MB  367MB   primary   ntfs            boot
2      368MB   121GB  120GB   primary   ntfs
3      121GB   142GB  21.0GB  primary   ntfs
4      142GB   160GB  18.5GB  extended
5      142GB   144GB  2047MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
6      144GB   160GB  16.4GB  logical   ext4

=================== parted -lm:

BYT;
/dev/sda:160GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:ATA WDC WD1600AAJS-2;
1:1049kB:368MB:367MB:ntfs::boot;
2:368MB:121GB:120GB:ntfs::;
3:121GB:142GB:21.0GB:ntfs::;
4:142GB:160GB:18.5GB:::;
5:142GB:144GB:2047MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
6:144GB:160GB:16.4GB:ext4::;

=================== lsblk:
KNAME TYPE FSTYPE   SIZE LABEL     MODEL    UUID
sda   disk        149.1G           WDC WD16
sda1  part ntfs     350M System Reserved
52BA189CBA187EA3
sda2  part ntfs     112G                    6C46240A4623D41C
sda3  part ntfs    19.5G                    D2220018220003E7
sda4  part            1K
sda5  part swap     1.9G                    f906300b-43ae-416b-90cc-2f0d2d592f2d
sda6  part ext4    15.3G                    64120f6b-4e16-458a-bdef-61bf3d83337f
sr0   rom          1024M           CDDVDW S

KNAME ROTA RO RM STATE   MOUNTPOINT
sda      1  0  0 running
sda1     1  0  0         /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
sda2     1  0  0         /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
sda3     1  0  0         /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
sda4     1  0  0
sda5     1  0  0         [SWAP]
sda6     1  0  0         /
sr0      1  0  1 running


=================== mount:
/dev/sda6 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=abhishek)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda1 type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda2 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda3 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda3 type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)


=================== ls:
/sys/block/sda (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 sda6 size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/sys/block/sr0 (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/dev (filtered):  agpgart autofs block bsg btrfs-control bus cdrom char console core cpu cpu_dma_latency cuse disk dri ecryptfs fb0 fd full fuse hidraw0 hpet input kmsg log lp0 mapper mcelog mem net network_latency network_throughput null parport0 port ppp psaux ptmx pts random rfkill rtc rtc0 sda sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 sda6 sg0 sg1 shm snapshot snd sr0 stderr stdin stdout uhid uinput urandom vfio vga_arbiter vhci vhost-net zero
ls /dev/mapper:  control
ls: cannot access : No such file or directory

=================== df -Th:

Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6      ext4       15G  3.9G   11G  28% /
none           tmpfs     4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev           devtmpfs  734M   12K  734M   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     149M  1.1M  148M   1% /run
none           tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none           tmpfs     744M  160K  744M   1% /run/shm
none           tmpfs     100M   48K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1      fuseblk   350M  238M  113M  68% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda2      fuseblk   112G   39G   74G  35% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sda3      fuseblk    20G  3.2G   17G  16% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3

=================== fdisk -l:

Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xece870cb

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      718847      358400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          718848   235522047   117401600    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       235522048   276482047    20480000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       276484094   312580095    18048001    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       276484096   280481791     1998848   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       280483840   312580095    16048128   83  Linux



=================== Recommended repair
The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub2 of sda6 into the MBR of sda.
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s   fix-windows-boot


Quantity of real Windows: 1
WinSE in sda2
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/Boot’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/BCD’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/BCD.LOG’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/BCD.LOG1’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/BCD.LOG2’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/bg-BG’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/BOOTSTAT.DAT’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/cs-CZ’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/da-DK’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/de-DE’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/el-GR’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/en-GB’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/en-US’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/es-ES’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/et-EE’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/fi-FI’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/Fonts’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/fr-FR’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/hr-HR’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/hu-HU’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/it-IT’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/ja-JP’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/ko-KR’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/lt-LT’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/lv-LV’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/memtest.exe’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/nb-NO’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/nl-NL’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/pl-PL’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/pt-BR’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/pt-PT’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/qps-ploc’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/Resources’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/ro-RO’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/ru-RU’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/sk-SK’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/sl-SI’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/sr-Latn-CS’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/sv-SE’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/tr-TR’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/uk-UA’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/zh-CN’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/zh-HK’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/zh-TW’: Read-only file system
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/bootmgr’: Read-only file system
Copied Win boot files from sda1 to sda2
/mnt/boot-sav/sda2/ may need repair.

*******lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2772] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:d606]
Kernel driver in use: i915
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:27d8] (rev 01)
*******

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1,grub-install (GRUB) 2.

Reinstall the GRUB of sda6 into the MBR of sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: Sector 32 is already in use by the program `FlexNet'; avoiding it.  This software may cause boot or other problems in future.  Please ask its authors not to store data in the boot track.
Installation finished. No error reported.
grub-install /dev/sda: exit code of grub-install /dev/sda:0

(zenity:17523): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory place/72 of theme MBuntu-OSX has no size field

FlexNet detected. Please backup your data before this operation. Do you want to continue? yes
dd if=/dev/sda of=/var/log/boot-sav/log/2015-05-02__11h15boot-repair16/sda/before_wiping.img bs=512 count=2047 seek=1
2047+0 records in
2047+0 records out
WIPE sda : 2047 sectors * 512 bytes
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=2047 seek=1
2047+0 records in
2047+0 records out
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
grub-install /dev/sda: exit code of grub-install /dev/sda:0

update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-30-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 8 (loader) on /dev/sda1
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
mount /dev/sda1 : Error code 14
mount -r /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
mount /dev/sda2 : Error code 14
mount -r /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda6/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.


The boot files of [The OS now in use - Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)
```

I have used system restore from disk but it doesn't work. Says try again later every time.

Comment: have you tried this `mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot-sav/sda2`

Comment: Where should I try this?

Comment: did you try repairing the windows using windows CD/DVD?

Comment: Yes. I did that. Doesn't work. Gives an error on system restore. When I used "Repair my Computer" the blue logo appeared and the progress bar went from 1 to 100% and then again rebooted with the blanl screen and command prompt like input. But, however, it removed Ubuntu.

Comment: Use that command in the terminal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8 no longer boots after Grub wiped out the Windows Bootsector](http://askubuntu.com/questions/263606/windows-8-no-longer-boots-after-grub-wiped-out-the-windows-bootsector)